# Mock Web API HTTPResponseMessage C# Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, tdd, moq

I want to create a unit test method for the below method which is receiving a file upload "text file" data and parsing it, I tried to use Moq and created a method but I am still very confused in the concept, I need a sample code, I've read many stackover flow questions but it is all for Controllers not Web API
the method used

```
// Enable both Get and Post so that our jquery call can send data, and get a status
        [HttpGet]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Upload()
        {
            // Get a reference to the file that our jQuery sent. Even if multiple files, they will
            // all be their own request and be the 0 index

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count>0)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];

                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                        if (!IsFileFormatSupported(extension))
                        {
                            var objectSerialized = SerializeData(GetError( GlobalResources.NotSupportedFileExtension));
                            return BadResponse(objectSerialized);
                        }
                        var path = SaveFileGetPath(file);
                        var result = GetPaySlips(path);
                        var SerializedData = SerializeData(result);
                        return OkResponse(SerializedData);
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception exception)
                    {
                        var SerializedData = SerializeData(GetError( GlobalResources.CouldNotReadFile + " " + exception.Message));
                        return BadResponse(SerializedData);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var SerializedData = SerializeData(GetError(file.FileName + " " +  GlobalResources.FileisCorrupt));
                    return BadResponse(SerializedData);
                }
            }else
            {
                var SerializedData = SerializeData(GetError( GlobalResources.FileisCorrupt));
                return BadResponse(SerializedData);
            }
        }
```

**the code I did so far**

```
    var FileUploadCtrl = new UploadController();
    Mock<HttpRequestMessage> cc = new Mock<HttpRequestMessage>();
    UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();

    // Mock<HttpPostedFileBase> file1 = new Mock<HttpPostedFileBase>();
    //file1.Expect(f=>f.InputStream).Returns(file1.Object.InputStream);
    //cc.Expect(ctx => ctx.Content).Returns(new retur);
   // cc.Expect(ctx => ctx.Content).Returns();
    var content = new ByteArrayContent( /* bytes in the file */ );
    content.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data");
    var controllerContext = new HttpControllerContext
    {
        Request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Content = new MultipartContent { content }
        }
    };

    //file1.Expect(d => d.FileName).Returns("FileTest.csv");
    //file1.Expect(d => d.InputStream).Returns(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)));
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    //var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost/api/upload");
    var route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}");
    var routeData = new HttpRouteData(route, new HttpRouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "FileUpload" } });



    FileUploadCtrl.ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(config, routeData, cc.Object);
    var r = FileUploadCtrl.Upload();
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(r, typeof(HttpResponseMessage));
```

Comment: Web API Controllers are also controllers that can be populated for unit and integration tests. The code under test in the above example needs to be refactored to be more maintainable and unit test friendly.  It is tightly coupled to static  classes, implementation concerns and also does not separate concerns. (SRP).

Comment: When practicing TDD, you should write a test first.  This will help you come up with a design that is testable.

Comment: thanks for your helpful input, but are you able to help on providing a sample for the desired scenario, file upload + web api mock up test ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? Maybe you can inject an IHttpContext interface instead of using HttpContext directly?